# get type of a component in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components, jradiobutton

I have a foreach loop that iterates all components in a jPanel, and I want to get the type of a components and check if it's a JRadioButton.

this is the code I tried:

```
 for (Component c : ((Container)jPanel1).getComponents() )
 {
     if(((JRadioButton)c).isSelected() && c.getComponentType()) {
         if(!listrep.contains(((JRadioButton)c).getText())) {
             ((JRadioButton)c).setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));;
         }
     }
 }
```

but it won't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: ah, an MCVE, a new one for me, thanks for showing this link!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the instanceof operator, but this will give your code a [bad code smell](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31) as does your entire plan. Better to put the components of interest into an ArrayList for ready reference.

Or even better, get the selected JRadioButton's ButtonModel directly from the ButtonGroup that you use to bind them together.

```
ButtonModel selectedModel = buttonGroup.getSelection();
if (selectedModel != null) {
 // use the selected button's model here
}
```

Comment: Love the quote in that link.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Component c : jpanel1.getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof JRadioButton) {
                //Do what you need to do, if you need to call JRadioButton methods
                //you will need to cast c to a JRadioButton first
            }
}
```